# Find distinct Combinations of Array

Tags: c++, arrays, stack-smash

I'm trying to find all possible combinations of a given array.
I found a solution [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/). I slightly adapted this approach since I need not only to have combinations with a fixed number of combinatioins but also all possible combinations up to a specific point. This is why I added a for loop to solve this. I ran into a problem because this solution only works for an array of size 15. Else I'm going to get a **stack smashing** and the program terminates. Anybody know how to mitigate this?

````
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;



void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[],
                     int start, int end,
                     int index, int r);

// The main function that prints
// all combinations of size r
// in arr[] of size n. This function
// mainly uses combinationUtil()
void printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r)
{
    // A temporary array to store
    // all combination one by one
    int data[r];

    // Print all combination using
    // temprary array 'data[]'
    combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n - 1, 0, r);
}

/* arr[] ---> Input Array
data[] ---> Temporary array to
store current combination
start & end ---> Staring and
Ending indexes in arr[]
index ---> Current index in data[]
r ---> Size of a combination to be printed */
void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[],
                     int start, int end,
                     int index, int r)
{
    // Current combination is ready
    // to be printed, print it
    if (index == r)
    {
        
        cout << "bits to set" << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
        {
            std::cout << data[j] << " ";
            z(data[j]) = 1;
        }

        cout << endl
             << z << endl;
        /*  for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
             cout << data[j] << " ";
         cout << endl;
         return; */
    }

    // replace index with all possible
    // elements. The condition "end-i+1 >= r-index"
    // makes sure that including one element
    // at index will make a combination with
    // remaining elements at remaining positions
    for (int i = start; i <= end &&
                        end - i + 1 >= r - index;
         i++)
    {
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i + 1,
                        end, index + 1, r);
    }
}

// Driver code
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    for (int r = 1; r <= 10; r++)
    {
        // int r = 10;
        printCombination(arr, n, r);
    }
}```
````

Comment: `int data[r];` is not valid C++, (it uses VLA extensions), use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: [Fixed version](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/774c2e130d16bc2f) (No `z`, and reactivate commented return)...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got it running. So by doing the data.data() I get a pointer to the first element of the contents of the vector. Is that correct?